# Unknown Cipher?

Tags: cipher

IF9fICAgX18gICAgIF9fXyAgX18gICAgICBfXyAgIF9fICAgX18gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBfX18gICBfXyAgIF9fICANCi8gX2AgLyAgXCAgICAgfCAgLyAgXCAgICB8ICBcIC8gIFwgfF9fKSAgL1wgICB8XC98IHwgfFwgfCB8X18gICB8X18pIC8gX2AgDQpcX18+IFxfXy8gICAgIHwgIFxfXy8gICAgfF9fLyBcX18vIHwgICAgL35+XCAgfCAgfCB8IHwgXHwgfF9fXyAufF9fKSBcX18+IA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgDQogX18gICBfX18gIF9fICAgICAgICBfXyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIA0KfCAgXCB8X18gIHxfXykgfCAgfCAvIF9gICAgICAgICAgICAgIA0KfF9fLyB8X19fIHxfXykgXF9fLyBcX18+IA==

Comment: Well the only clue I have it says it is a "Bonus" nothing more unfortunately to go on.

Comment: (Lively commentary about this puzzle’s solvability, our site scope, and migration potential has been removed; I think some folks learned something today but we don’t need to keep it all in the comments :)  Do note that the discussion at [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717) is relevant even if the puzzle is just one you found somewhere; not all puzzles are a good fit for Puzzling.SE. That aside, this was unattributed 3rd party content, and arguably spammy... even though it is on-topic for subject matter, it should and will remain closed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you use

> [Base64 Decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/)

You will get

> [image: GO TO DOPAMINE.BG DEBUG]
>
>  **GO TO DOPAMINE.BG DEBUG**

Additional note:

> It's a good guess to use Base64 decoder as the string ends with several equal signs (=).

Comment: Wow. I'm actually super impressed. Wow. Wow.